# Generating string of code from properties of nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have a button that should "compile" a command that's going to be used in the terminal.
Keeping the explanation simple:
Rows with six inputs inside them, row is an object, and the inputs inside is properties with the value of the inputs being the value of the property.
Write a terminal command from the input data.

The JSON object looks like this

```
formsData = {
  transfer_1: {
    host_1: "t1_host1",
    host_2: "t1_host2",
    user_1: "t1_user1",
    user_2: "t1_user2",
    password_1: "t1_password1",
    password_2: "t1_password2"
  },
  transfer_2: {
    host_1: "t2_host1",
    host_2: "t2_host2",
    user_1: "t2_user1",
    user_2: "t2_user2",
    password_1: "t2_password1",
    password_2: "t2_password2"
  }
}
```

I want to put all values from transfer_1 into a command for the terminal that looks like this:

```
./imapsync --host1 t1_host1 --user1 t1_user1 --password1 t1_password1 
--host2 t1_host2 --user2 t1_user2 --password2 t1_password2;
```

I wanted to do something like this:

```
var command = "";
for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(formsData).length; i++) {
    command += 
    "./imapsync_bin_Darwin " +
    "--host1 " + formsData[i].host_1 + " " +
    "--user1 " + formsData[i].user_1 + " " +
    "--password1 " + formsData[i].password_1 + " " +
    "--host2 " + formsData[i].host_2 + " " +
    "--user2 " + formsData[i].user_2 + " " +
    "--password2 " + formsData[i].password_2 + "; ";
}
console.log(command);
```

But all I get is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'host_1' of undefined
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you so much for the quick answers! It works now thanks to you guys, and I've become a little smarter now I hope :-)

Comment: because you do not have an array,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of you need to get it by keyname, like that (quick example);

```js
var formsData = {
  transfer_1: {
    host_1: "t1_host1",
    host_2: "t1_host2",
    user_1: "t1_user1",
    user_2: "t1_user2",
    password_1: "t1_password1",
    password_2: "t1_password2"
  },
  transfer_2: {
    host_1: "t2_host1",
    host_2: "t2_host2",
    user_1: "t2_user1",
    user_2: "t2_user2",
    password_1: "t2_password1",
    password_2: "t2_password2"
  }
};

var command = "",
    keys = Object.keys(formsData);

for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    command += 
    "./imapsync_bin_Darwin " +
    "--host1 " + formsData[keys[i]].host_1 + " " +
    "--user1 " + formsData[keys[i]].user_1 + " " +
    "--password1 " + formsData[keys[i]].password_1 + " " +
    "--host2 " + formsData[keys[i]].host_2 + " " +
    "--user2 " + formsData[keys[i]].user_2 + " " +
    "--password2 " + formsData[keys[i]].password_2 + "; ";
}
console.log(command);
```

Comment: @Jonasw yep, you right, Jonas, hope OP would use it like that :)

Comment: I have literally worked since 8 AM on this, and it's 1:30 PM now. You are the man!!
How would I implement keys.length?

Comment: @CasperEngl well, basically, Jonas meant (as I understood) to use `for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)` instead of what currently is in `for` string :)

Comment: @DanilGholtsman Thanks, that works aswell. This is my first time working with objects in this way, thank you for the enlightenment :-)

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing array and object.

`formsData` is an object, but you are using it like an array (trying to get `length` and iterating over it with an index). Use `for (var key in formsData)` with `hasOwnProperty` check afterwards for objects.

Like this (untested, but you get the idea):

```
var command = "";
for (var key in formsData) {
    if (!formsData.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    command += 
    "./imapsync_bin_Darwin " +
    "--host1 " + formsData[key].host_1 + " " +
    "--user1 " + formsData[key].user_1 + " " +
    "--password1 " + formsData[key].password_1 + " " +
    "--host2 " + formsData[key].host_2 + " " +
    "--user2 " + formsData[key].user_2 + " " +
    "--password2 " + formsData[key].password_2 + "; ";
}
console.log(command);
```

You would probably want to break after the first key ("transfer_1") in order to get what you actually want ("put all values from transfer_1 into a command"). So you could actually go without the loop and just assign `var key = "transfer_1"`.

For a shorter approach, you can do it more beautifully like this:

```js
var formsData = {
  transfer_1: {
    host_1: "t1_host1",
    host_2: "t1_host2",
    user_1: "t1_user1",
    user_2: "t1_user2",
    password_1: "t1_password1",
    password_2: "t1_password2"
  },
  transfer_2: {
    host_1: "t2_host1",
    host_2: "t2_host2",
    user_1: "t2_user1",
    user_2: "t2_user2",
    password_1: "t2_password1",
    password_2: "t2_password2"
  }
}

var command = "./imapsync_bin_Darwin ";
for (var key in formsData.transfer_1) {
    if (!formsData.transfer_1.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    command += "--" + key + " " + formsData.transfer_1[key] + " ";
}
command = command.slice(0,-1) + ";";
console.log(command);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```js
var formsData = {
  transfer_1: {
    host_1: "t1_host1",
    host_2: "t1_host2",
    user_1: "t1_user1",
    user_2: "t1_user2",
    password_1: "t1_password1",
    password_2: "t1_password2"
  },
  transfer_2: {
    host_1: "t2_host1",
    host_2: "t2_host2",
    user_1: "t2_user1",
    user_2: "t2_user2",
    password_1: "t2_password1",
    password_2: "t2_password2"
  }
};
var command = "";
var keys=Object.keys(formsData);
for (var i=0,l=keys.length;i<l;i++) {
    t=formsData[keys[i]];
    command += 
    "./imapsync_bin_Darwin " +
    "--host1 " + t.host_1 + " " +
    "--user1 " + t.user_1 + " " +
    "--password1 " + t.password_1 + " " +
    "--host2 " + t.host_2 + " " +
    "--user2 " + t.user_2 + " " +
    "--password2 " + t.password_2 + "; ";
}
console.log(command);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `i` in your loop is counting keys, and there are 2 keys in `formsData`. So `i` is taking values 0 and 1. When you do `formsData[i]` you are actually doing `formsData[0]` or `formsData[1]`, both of these do not exist. This is why you get undefined.

You may want to try `formsData[keys[i]]`. This way `keys[i]` is taking values "transfer_1" and "transfer_2", so `formsData["transfer_1"].host_1`, suddenly becomes valid.